# Incompatible pointer type, expected float * but argument is of type float (*)[2]

Tags: c, pointers, arguments

```
#define N 5
#define Nv 2

float Cities[N][Nv]={ {0,1}, {3,4}, {1,2}, {5,1} ,{8,9}};
void PrintVec2(float *a, int n) {   
   
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < (n / 2); i++) printf("\n%f %f", a[2 * i], a[2 * i + 1]);
    printf("\n");
}

//somewhere I call this
PrintVec2(Cities,N*Nv);
```

New*Nv is a number, integer. How to fix this warning?

Comment: Why not match the types of the argument and what is passed?

Comment: I don't seem to get how.

Comment: You've shown how `PrintVec2(Cities,New*Nv);` is called. Now, please edit your post to include the exact declaration for `Cities`, show how you populate it, provide a [mcve].

Comment: What is `New` ?

Comment: Consider New=N.

Comment: I get a warning that should cause you some concern:  `warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'float [5][2]' to parameter of type 'float *' 
`

Comment: `PrintVec2(Cities,N*Nv);` => `PrintVec2(&Cities[0][0],N*Nv);`

Comment: Are there any reason not to use `void PrintVec2(float a[][2], int n) `? (for example, want to support other kinds of array?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prototype:

```
void PrintVec2(float *a, int n)
```

Does not match the input parameter:

```
PrintVec2(Cities,N*Nv);
```

The function prototype is looking for the address of the array.  Change it to send `&Cities[0][0]`:

```
PrintVec2(&Cities[0][0],N*Nv);
```

Comment: is it worth the answer?

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland - If it is a sincere question, then yes, it is worth an answer.

Comment: It was a sincere question on my end, works fine now, thanks!!